# Create 2 views exposed filters,one for parent term and one for child term

Tags: views

I want to create a view with two exposed filters,the first one with a parent term and the second one with a child term.Child term will be populated depending on the parent term that was selected on the first filter.

I want these two filters to exist always,not appearing/dissapearing of exposed filter of child term.

I.e. I don't want to use Simple Hierarchical select or Hierararhical select.
Is there a module for that?I am really impressed that such module doesn't exist in Drupal Or is this possible with some Javascript to disable the effects on Simple hierarchical select?